# Node Child process is running continuously without closing after getting the data

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process, dom-events, spawn

I am working on a loopback project where I need to run a background job. Spawn node child process. Since I am beginner, documentation is little confusing. https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options

parent.js

```
const path = require("path");

const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

let child = spawn('node', [__dirname + '../../worker/worker.js']);

child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
      console.log('data available ' + data);
});

child.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
     console.log('There was an error: ' + data);
});
```

worker.js

```
function jobListener() {


    let query = { jobname: "countProvider"}
    let result = Job.findOne({ where: query }, function(err, instance) {
        if(err) {
            console.log('Error', err);
        }
      // console.log(instance);
    });

    while (!result) { 
        console.log(result);
       // await sleep(5000);
        console.log('checking for job in mongodb with a delay of 5 seconds');
    }
    if(result) {
        fetchProcedureRequest();
    }
}

jobListener();

function fetchProcedureRequest() {
    console.log('Fetching pREquest');
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is I am getting the data in child process. But how can I close/exit the process when data is available in parent. Somebody please help  and any suggestion will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use this, found here [How to kill childprocess in nodejs?](http://var%20proc%20=%20require('child_process').spawn('mongod');%20proc.kill('SIGINT');)

`var proc = require('child_process').spawn('mongod');
proc.kill('SIGINT');`

Comment: Where could I used this?  Inside this code? child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
      console.log('data available ' + data);
});

Comment: yes, you can try child.kill('SIGINT') inside child.stdout.on('data' ...